# Getting "Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate" on a popular website

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install sqlbak on a Google cloud VM running Ubuntu 20.04. For some reason, it is unable to validate the SSL certificate.

```
sudo wget -O - https://sqlbak.com/deb/key/deb.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

returns

```
--2021-09-26 19:10:56--  https://sqlbak.com/deb/key/deb.gpg.key
Resolving sqlbak.com (sqlbak.com)... 209.133.198.58
Connecting to sqlbak.com (sqlbak.com)|209.133.198.58|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify sqlbak.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to sqlbak.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

To further validate the problem, I ran

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername sqlbak.com -connect sqlbak.com:443
```

This returns `Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate`:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = sqlbackupandftp.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = sqlbackupandftp.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGBjCCBO6gAwIBAgISA7es6ONnKRzNDXYStWGIAsCkMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
....
AxD26axM1om2cs27qPwicdDdKwno1osRy1tdX8PlYaTIYxM47mobmYTutmMpJ5OA
mbCQFlo9SFboAA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = sqlbackupandftp.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3265 bytes and written 395 bytes
Verification error: unable to get local issuer certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 3072 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
...
---
DONE
```

I tried running the same check via another Google VM instance running Debian in another zone. But there was no error. `Verification: OK`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = sqlbackupandftp.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = sqlbackupandftp.com
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGBjCCBO6gAwIBAgISA7es6ONnKRzNDXYStWGIAsCkMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
...
AxD26axM1om2cs27qPwicdDdKwno1osRy1tdX8PlYaTIYxM47mobmYTutmMpJ5OA
mbCQFlo9SFboAA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = sqlbackupandftp.com

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3265 bytes and written 395 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 3072 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
...
---
DONE
```

**Why is one VM showing SSL error whereas another VM working fine?**

**Observations**

1. Certificate is exactly the same in both responses.
2. Valid response contains `depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3 verify return:1`. Is there a hint in here?

For solutions, I tried reinstalling ca-certificates

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates 

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
sudo apt-get -f install
```

PS:
As @dave_thompson_085 mentioned, the problem in Ubuntu server is that the root certificate isn't recognized. How do I install it, since purging ca-certificates and reinstalling doesn't work either.

Comment: `depth=2 ... DST X3` is significant; it means that system has the relevant root in its truststore aka 'bundle', while the other one doesn't. `verify return:1` in `s_client` is mostly meaningless, because it was designed as a test/debug tool and overrides the callback return, so that you get `Verify return:` nonzero (in the session object decode you redacted) but the connection proceeds anyway. BTW, Ubuntu 20.04 should have OpenSSL 1.1.1 which no longer needs you to specify `-servername` on `s_client` (but it doesn't hurt). ...

Comment: ... Why one Google VM has this root and another doesn't you'd have to investigate what the VMs are running and how it was installed/configured/updated. FWIW my _personal_ Ubuntu20.04 VM with package `ii  ca-certificates      20210119~20.04.1 all          Common CA certificates` does have DST X3 -- and also ISRG X1, which I thought LE had finally started using about a year ago.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I reinstalled the ca-certificates, yet the relevant root is not available in the truststore. As mentioned in my question above.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It boils down to installing relevant root certificate in ubuntu. But why isn't reinstalling `ca-certificates` installing the missing certificate?

Answer (score 1):

As a makeshift solution, I have manually added this website's certificate to locally trusted certificates.

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect sqlbak.com:443 | \
  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | \
  sudo tee '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/sqlbak_com.crt'
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

But this still doesn't resolve the original issue. Why isn't this certificate recognised by default?